# Armature Rig Deforms Half The Rig

Tags: rigging

I am very new to blender, I have rigged a few characters in the past and I wanted to try rigging only the limbs to this character.

When I parent the mesh and armature with automatic weights, it works exactly how I expect it to on one half of the character and the other side deforms and doesn't follow the bones as I want them to (It bends out of the bones and gets skinnier the more it rotates and shifts position).

I tried looking for a solution but couldn't really find anything that looks like it would help. I don't know if its the rig itself I'm using, but I tried making one from scratch and then tried a meta rig I modified to fit but both give the same results. This only happens when the left and right limbs are one mesh but if the two sides were separate meshes it works fine but is just a big inconvenience.

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Try applying your mirror modifier before binding your mesh to the rig.

Comment: I was able to pin it on a weight problem and got it fixed with a little bit of weight painting. But anyways, I want to delete this post now but since I posted it as a guest I can’t delete it even after I’ve linked the e-mail to create this account. I don’t know if you guys can help, thanks in advance